# Volley Android Autenticación básica Método GET

Tags: android-studio, webservice, android-volley, http-get

Estoy tratando de usar la librería Volley para hacer una petición de tipo GET, pero necesito pasarle los parámetros de autenticación.

En Python seria de esta forma:

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
session.auth = ("ff20f250a7b3a414781d1abe11cd8cee", "fb453577d11294359058a9ae13c94713")
b = session.get('https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/trading/balance').json()
print(b)
```

Cuando uso el Postman para probar el WebServices, tengo que hacerlo de esta forma y funciona correctamente:

```
https://ff20f250a7b3a414781d1abe11cd8cee:fb453577d11294359058a9ae13c94713@api.hitbtc.com/api/2/order
```

Pero al hacer la petición en Android con Volley y tambien con HTTPUrlConnection y nada...

Aquí va el código que estoy montando en Android Studio

```
//HTTPUrlConnection------
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        con.setDoInput( true );

                // stuff the Authorization request header
                byte[] encodedPassword = ( userName + ":" + password ).getBytes();
                BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
                con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", encoder.encode(encodedPassword));
                con.setRequestProperty( "Authorization",
                        "Basic " + encoder.encode( encodedPassword ) );

        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = con.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                int c;
                while( ( c = is.read() ) != -1 ) {
                    buf.append( (char) c );
                }
                con.disconnect();
```

Por favor, Ayuda!!!!!

Comment: Como le paso los parámetros de autenticación básica por esta vía? JsonRequest jsonTradingBalance = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/trading/balance", null,

Comment: Hola Rubén, bienvenido a SOes. Puedes poner lo que has intentado en Android Studio? Para ver lo que falla donde dices que no funciona con Volley y con HttpUrlConnection, así te podremos ayudar. Has probado con HttpClient?

Comment: Hola Pablo, ahora mismo te subo el código...

Comment: No he probado con HttpClient... déjame intentarlo.

Comment: Este es un ejemplo por consola de lo que quiero pedir: curl -X GET -u "ff20f250a7b3a414781d1abe11cd8cee:fb453577d11294359058a9ae13c94713" \
     "https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/trading/balance"

Comment: Prueba con este llaves que están habilitadas: `https://d37f9d9fa41d3f0cb711f56ca304d171:12beee9b292b5d141b72893d36d127cb@api.hitbtc.com/api/2/trading/balance`

Comment: Yo quiero cargar ese JSON que devuelve en mi APP

Comment: Puedes probarla con el PostMan: https://www.getpostman.com/apps